# How would you say, "I speak a little bit German"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, adverb

I put this into Google Translate, and it came up with,

> Ich spreche ein wenig Deutsch.

Is this correct? I doubt so. When I look up *wenig* I find that it's an adjective, not an adverb, and obviously the sentence requires an adverb.

What's the best way to say, "I speak a little German"?

Comment: German adjectives can generally act as adverbs, but *wenig* is actually more often an adverb: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wenig_kaum_unbedeutend_selten

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32832/why-is-it-gut-not-gutes-in-ich-spreche-sehr-gut-englisch

Comment: It won't get you voted into some poets or literature society but most people will understand what you mean if you say that.

Comment: How is it obvious that an adverb is required? If the word is modifying "Deutsch", then it's an adjective. And the great thing about trying to tell someone that you don't know much German is that if your statement isn't grammatically correct, that in itself is communicating the sentiment in question.

Comment: @Acccumulation That assumption of mine was wrong. I learned recently that "ein wenig" is actually a determiner.

Comment: How could nobody post https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P22gPwGuLa0 yet?

Comment: It may be right that *wenig* is best not considered an adverb here, but the thing is, the German language does not really care what your grammar calls the parts of the sentence, and adverbs work in that position.

Comment: To say 'My German is limited to "Bitte ein bier"'. My German friend corrected me, saying 'bite zwei bier' is better'.

Comment: From the title "I speak a little bit German" is not even correct English. Either "I speak a little German" or "I speak a little bit of German" will work

Comment: I think you meant "I speak a little bit *of* German" as this is correct English and gives the answer you quote in Google Translate. On the other hand when I type "I speak a little bit German" it gives "Ich spreche ein bisschen deutsch", which suggests that it has understood "a little bit German" as an adverbial phrase rather like saying someone *sounds* "a little bit German". So it makes a big difference exactly what you type. As in any language, leaving out one very small word can make a big difference.

Comment: Ich spreche ein bisschen Deutsch.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There exist three ways of how to use the adjective *wenig* in German:

1. As an attribute of a noun: **A small amount of something**

   > In diesem Glas ist **wenig** Wasser.
   >   In this glass is **little** water.
   >
   > Ich sehe **wenige** Autos.
   >   I see **few** cars.
2. As an adverbial (which is not an adverb!): **To an insignificant extent**

   > Das kümmert mich **wenig.**
   >   I care **little** (about that).
   >
   > Deine Äußerung war **wenig** hilfreich.
   >   Your statement was **not very** helpful.
3. In combination with *»ein«* (»ein wenig«): **Synonym of *»etwas«***

   > Ich habe noch **ein wenig** Milch. Möchtest du sie?
   >   Ich habe noch **etwas** Milch. Möchtest du sie?
   >   I still have **some** milk. Do you want it?
   >
   > Ich fühle mich **ein wenig** unwohl hier.
   >   Ich fühle mich **etwas** unwohl hier.
   >   I feel **somewhat** uncomfortable here.

But *etwas* is not an adjective, and it also isn't an adverb. It is a pronoun, to be more precise: It is an indefinite pronoun (*»Indefinitpronomen«* in German). But when used in the meaning where you can replace it with *ein wenig*, you also can say that it is a *Gradpartikel* or a *Steigerungspartikel* (which are synonyms). I don't know the official English terms, but i would translate this as *grade particles* or *enhancing particles*.

Examples of words, that belong to this part of speech are:

> Ich habe **etwas** Geld. Dein neues Auto ist **recht** groß. Ich habe dich **sehr** gern. Du machst mich **überaus** glücklich. Dr. Steiner war **ungemein** freundlich. Das ist **weitaus** mehr als ich erwartet habe. Hast du dich schon **einigermaßen** erholt?
>
> I have **some** money. Your new car is **quite** big. I like you **very** much. You make me **very** happy. Dr. Steiner was **extremely** friendly. That is **far** more than I expected. Have you already recovered **to some degree**?

Technically *"ein wenig"* does not belong to this group. Technically it consists of two words, the first is an indefinite article, and the second is an adjective, but together both words function like one grade particle, and therefore you can use them in this manner.

Also the word *bisschen*, when combined with *ein* behaves this way.

In the following sentences the bold marked parts of speech are synonyms:

> Ich spreche **ein wenig** Deutsch.
>   Ich spreche **ein bisschen** Deutsch.
>   Ich spreche **etwas** Deutsch.
>
> I speak **a little bit of** German.
>   I speak **a little** German.
>   I speak **some** German.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be _"Ich sehe wenig**e** Autos"_, as _Auto_ is a countable noun?

Comment: @moooeeeep: Nach meinem Sprachgefühl sind beide Varianten möglich, aber es kann durchaus sein, dass nur regional begrenzt der Fall ist, daher habe ich das entsprechende Wort korrigiert.

Comment: Joined the community to upvote this answer

Comment: _Gradpartikel_ sounds like it ought to mean ‘particle of degree’; many parts of speech in different languages are traditionally called “X of degree” in English, though I don’t know if that’s also true of _Gradpartikeln_ in German. _Steigerungspartikel_ must surely be a ‘particle of comparison’ (with _Steigerung_ having here its linguistic meaning related to forming comparatives and other comparisons). Also, I cannot see how _wenig_ in 2 is different from an adverb. It is certainly an adverb in the English translation, as it modifies the verb, and I don’t see how it wouldn’t be in German, too.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Look here about the difference between adjective, adverb (both are word classes) and adverbial (a grammatical function) (in German): [Sind adverbielle Adjektive Adjektive oder Adverbien?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/35454/1487)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now—you were talking about functionality, rather than word class. To make that clear, I suggest you modify “as adverbial” (which gets parsed as “as an adverbial” in English, being interpreted as a noun indicating a word class) to “adverbially”. You might even modify 1 to “attributively” as well to make a better parallel. You can always add that adverbial usage does not necessarily make the word an adverb.

Comment: You make an interesting point about *ein wenig* being an adverbial, not an adverb proper. I might post a follow-up question on Linguistics.SE asking about the grammatical difference between the English phrase "a little" and the German phrase "ein wenig".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Names for grammatical functions are nouns, like all names. "Adverbial" is such a name and therefore a noun. But "adverbially" is an adverb, and as an adverb (i.e. as not being a noun) it can't be a name of anything. Saying "as an adverbially" would be grammatically wrong! Also "As an attributively" would be wrong! "Attribute" is a noun, and a name, and this is how used this words.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Syntactic functionality is not usually expressed in nominal form in English, but _descriptively_, i.e., as adjectives or adverbs. _Adverbial_ is not commonly used as a noun in English grammar (despite the Wikipedia article); rather we usually say that something functions _adverbially_ or _as an adverbial phrase_, using an adverbial or adjectival descriptor instead. When I suggested changing “as adverbial” to “adverbially”, I meant precisely that—not that it should be changed to “as an adverbially”, which is indeed ungrammatical.

Comment: In other words, I meant that a more common and idiomatic-sounding way to write your first two points would be something along the lines of “1) Attributively, modifying a noun phrase” and “2) Adverbially (which does not necessarily make it an adverb itself)”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Do you really say "This pronoun is used *subjectively*" instead of "This pronoun is used as the subject"? Or "*objectively*" instead of "as an object"? Both, *subject* and *object* are nouns that are used as names of grammatical functions; *predicate* is another one. And *attribute* and *adverbial* are just two more names of grammatical functions.

Comment: No, _subjectively_ and _objectively_ are not that common, though they are sometimes used; “used as subject/object” or “used in subject/object position” are more common. That may be due to the much more common meanings of that particular pair of adjectives/adverbs, I’m not sure. But we definitely never say that an NP used attributively is used “as an adjectival” either, nor that one used verbally is used “as a verbal”. Certain functions go against the trend, but most tend to be expressed descriptively, not nominally (and not as a nominal either).

Comment: … And both _adverb(ial(ly))_ and _attribut(e/ive(ly))_ are instances of functions that do not go against the trend. The noun _attribute_ itself is not uncommon as such, but it is more common to speak of an adjective functioning attributively than as an attribute. The noun _adverbial_ **is** very uncommon.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: I don't agree with your definition of 'Gradpartikel'. When used before a noun, words and phrases that in other contexts can be 'Gradpartikeln' are 'determiners' or 'quantifiers', they take the place and the function of articles in these instances. Saying this I'm referring to '_etwas_ Milch', '_ein wenig_ Milch', '_etwas_ Deutsch', Duden grammar 2006 calls them 'Artikelwörter'. But there are more: '_jede Menge_ Geld', '_viel_ Zeit', '_genug_ Leute', '_mehrere_ Personen' and many others. (Duden. Die Grammatik 2006, pp. 316 - 337). (I hope I understood you correctly.)

Answer (score 39):

Your proposal is absolutely correct and hard to improve.

Alternatives:

> - Ich spreche ein bisschen Deutsch.
> - Ich spreche etwas Deutsch.

Or with self-criticism:

> - Mein Deutsch ist nicht besonders [gut].
> - Mein Deutsch lässt zu wünschen übrig.
> - Mein Deutsch ist eher schlecht.

Comment: Alternativ kann man in den ersten beiden Sätzen auch noch ein "nur" einschieben.

Comment: The part with the self-criticism feels very german :-)

Comment: Big difference. The first would be you owning up to not speaking the language well, the second could get you the question "so what are you going to do to improve it?" back :)

Comment: Ein Bisschen is better imo. "Mein Deutsch lässt zu wünschen übrig" is embarrasing.

Comment: I feel like if you know enough German to say the "...lässt zu wünschen übrig." example, then you know more than a little German.

Answer (score 14):

Colloquially, it is also widespread to "can" a language:

"Ich kann ein bisschen Deutsch" or "Ich kann ein wenig Deutsch". "I can a little German" (let the boy out of the Weck jar, now!).

This is not 100% grammatically correct, but sounds less weird than it would in English: We have "können" (to be able/allowed to, "to can") as a proper verb. It is used very similar to "know" in the english language to refer to a skill ("I know a little german", "I know karate", "I know fixing it").

Comment: just add "sprechen" at the end and it becomes quite correct.

Comment: Yes. But capitalization becomes hairy at that point :)

Comment: Then we will simply have to switch plan if it's not working for us.

Comment: Why would the capitalization become hairy? Wouldn't it simply be the same?

Comment: @FabioTurati it wouldn't be, it was just an attempt to intimidate.

Comment: "kann deutsch sprechen" und "kann Deutsch sprechen" are both valid - and would have the same meaning but for different grammatical reasons.

Answer (score 5):

As @Pollitzer already pointed out, the Google-translated version is (surprisingly) one of the most common ways to say "I speak a little german". And while there are many more valid alternatives pointed out in other answers, they all fail to mention the important part: The reason for this variant to be correct.

Even though "ein wenig" can indeed be used as an adverb, this would be used like "Ich gehe ein wenig spazieren"/"I'm taking a (little) walk". In your case though you do in fact **not** need an adverb, but a way to describe the amount of German you speak, i.e. an **<strike>adjective</strike> determiner** (as per ktm5124's comment). I might be overlooking something in English, but even there I'd wager the "little" relates to the language, not the speaking.

Comment: I believe that "a little" is actually a determiner, per jlawler's comment to my Linguistics post: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/25815/does-a-little-en-correspond-to-the-same-grammatical-class-as-ein-wenig-de.

Comment: If https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/4352/1593 is to be believed, then the Google-translated version being one of the most common ways to say something is hardly surprising.

Comment: @ktm5124 thanks for the correction, I edited the answer accordingly. This way it should be even clearer, how "wenig" relates to the language.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling yes indeed, I had already expected something like that to be the reason. Google has somewhat improved in the last years.

Answer (score 3):

Two good answers already, but to add one detail ...

If you only know a little German, you'll only be able to express this using what you know! In particular, if you're not that fluent, you need to lower expectations, so the fewer and simpler words the better really.

So *Ich kann* or *Ich spreche*, maybe *nur* if you've learnt it (to stress that it's only a little), and *ein bißchen Deutsch* is probably the way to go (since *bißchen* is the first word I learned for "little").

Answer (score 0):

Einfach gesagt:

Ich kann etwas Deutsch...

Comment: You may want to [edit] your answer and add why it is better than the [existing ones](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/38751/23).

Answer (score 0):

The best answer to convey what you are trying to say is:
Ich spreche nur etwas Deutsch (I speak only a little German)
or ich kann etwas Deutsch sprechen (I can speak a little German)

Answer (score 0):

There are already many good and some interesting suggestions and the especially the grammar part was already very well covered.

What I'm missing in all of the answers that you received so far are 2 aspects I find quite important regarding your final question:

> What's the best way to say, "I speak a little German"?

These aspects are

- The context
- And (maybe even more important) what you want to emphasize

**Some samples:**

Let's think of a job interview. They require some German, but you just started learning and want to point out that you're willing to improve. In this case I'd suggest something like ...

> Ich spreche noch nicht sehr gut Deutsch.

... or ...

> Mein Deutsch ist noch nicht sehr gut.

Here the *noch* emphasizes that you are in the process of progressing, which may be important in some situations.

Let's look at quite the opposite: You want to avoid that someone continues talking advanced German to you. In this case I'd suggest something like...

> Mein Deutsch ist sehr schlecht

... or ...

> Ich kann nur sehr wenig Deutsch

... or some other variants that were already suggested.

Of course there are many more contexts we can think of - probably so many that it won't make sense trying to cover all of them.

Answer (score -1):

Simple : "Ich spreche etwas Deutsch." which means i speak little bit of deutsch..

You can use this line as :

> "Ich spreche hindi, english und etwas Deutsch.."

which means "i speak hindi, english and little bit of german.."