# Zu welcher Wortart gehört »ein« in »ein wenig«

Tags: word-classes

Als ich [eine Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38750/how-would-you-say-i-speak-a-little-bit-german/38752#38752) zu einer anderen Frage schrieb, habe ich dort behauptet, die Phrase »ein wenig« bestünde aus einem unbestimmten Artikel und einem Adjektiv. Ich bin mir aber bezüglich des Wortes »ein« nicht ganz sicher, ob das wirklich stimmt. (Im Gegenteil: Ich bezweifle es, weiß aber keine besser passende Wortart.)

Um das genauer zu analysieren, möchte ich folgende Beispiele betrachten:

> 1. Deine Füße stinken **ein wenig.**
> 2. Die Musik ist **ein wenig** zu laut.
> 3. Ich habe noch **ein wenig** Milch.
> 4. Mich friert **ein wenig.**

Das Wort »ein« kann laut Wiktionary zu einer dieser Wortarten gehören:

- **(unbestimmter) Artikel**

  Beispiele:

  > **Ein** Junge singt auf der Straße. *(männlich, Nominativ)*
  >   Am Ufer steht **ein** Haus. *(sächlich, Nominativ)*
  >   Die Wahl fällt auf **ein** Mädchen. *(sächlich, Akkusativ)*

  In [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Artikel/index.html) steht aber über Artikel:

  > Der Artikel tritt immer zusammen mit einem Nomen auf.

  [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artikel_(Wortart)) weiß etwas ähnliches:

  > Ein Artikel *[...]* ist ein grammatisches Wort, das regelmäßig ein Substantiv (einschließlich Substantivierungen) begleitet.

  In den Beispielsätzen 1 bis 4 bezieht sich das Wort »ein« aber in keinem einzigen Fall auf ein Nomen, Substantiv oder eine Substantivierung. Daher glaube ich nicht, dass »ein« in diesen Fällen ein Artikel ist.
- **Numeral(e) (Zahlwort)**

  Beispiele:

  > Jeder bekommt nur **ein** Stück. *(der Zahlwert 1)*
  >   **Ein** Glas ist zerbrochen, alle anderen sind heil geblieben. *(ein ausgewähltes Exemplar aus einer größeren Gruppe)*

  Numerale haben gemeinsam, dass man sie durch andere Numerale ersetzen kann (wobei sich natürlich die Anzahl ändert, was eine Anpassung des Numerus erfordern kann, aber in jedem Fall entsteht dann ein halbwegs sinnvoller anderer Satz):

  > Jeder bekommt *zwei* Stück; *zwei* Gläser sind zerbrochen.

  Aber »Deine Füße stinken *zwei* wenig; die Musik ist *zwei* wenig zu laut« usw. ist Unsinn.

  Das Wort »ein« in »ein wenig« ist also ganz sicher kein Zahlwort.
- **Indefinitpronomen**

  Beispiele:

  > Bis auf **eine** sind alle Schülerinnen da.
  >   Was für **eines** hätten Sie denn gern?
  >   Davon wird **einem** ja schlecht!
  >   Hier hilft **einer** dem anderen.

  Auffallend an der Beugungstabelle des Indefinitpronomens *»ein«* ist, dass das Grundwort (das ungebeugte, drei Buchstaben lange Wort »ein«) selbst gar nicht auftaucht. Nur *»einer, eine, eines, einem, eine«* und *»eins«* (als Variante von *»eines«* im sächlichen Akkusativ) kommen vor.

  Schon allein aus diesem Grund kann »ein« in »ein wenig« kein Indefinitpronomen sein.
- **Adverb**

  Beispiele:

  > Eduard tritt ins Zimmer **ein.**
  >   Er geht hier **ein** und aus.
  >   Werner wusste weder **ein** noch aus.

  Laut Wiktionary kommt »ein« als Adverb nur in festen Wendungen (***ein*** und aus gehen, weder **ein** noch aus wissen) und als Teil von trennbaren Verben (**ein**treten, **ein**bringen, ...) vor. (Der Duden wählt für letzteres anstelle von *Adverb* die - wie ich meine passendere - Bezeichnung *Präfix*.)

  Eine Verbindung mit einem Verb liegt im Fall von »ein wenig« nicht vor (weder als Wendung, noch als Teil des Verbs), daher scheint mir auch diese Wortart nicht die richtige zu sein.
- **Adjektiv**

  Umgangssprachliches Synonym für *eingeschaltet.*
  Beispiel:

  > Das Licht ist nicht aus, sondern **ein.**
  >   Der Schalter war doch gerade noch **ein**, jetzt ist er aus.

  In »ein wenig« fehlt jeder Zusammenhang mit *eingeschaltet sein*, daher ist auch diese Wortart auszuschließen.

---

Zusammenfassend komme ich also zu dem Schluss, dass das Wort »ein« in »ein wenig« zu keiner der oben genannten Wortarten gehören kann. Aber zu irgend einer Wortart muss es doch gehören. Zu welcher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Wort ist ursprünglich ein Artikel. Die Konstruktion ist vergleichbar mit dem Ausdruck «ein bisschen», der erkennbar sich herleitet aus «ein Bisschen» (ein kleiner Biss). Da sie erstarrt ist, wird man sie insgesamt eher als ein (zusammengesetztes) Indefinitpronomen analysieren («man nehme *ein wenig* Salz» wie «man nehme *etwas* Salz») denn als eine partitive Apposition («man nehme *ein wenig* Salz» wie «man nehme *eine Messerspitze* Salz»).

Zu deinen Ersetzungsproben lässt sich noch Folgendes hinzufügen:

- Das Adverb «ein» würde sich durch «hin-» erweitern lassen («ein und aus» wird so zu «hinein und hinaus»). Dies geht offensichtlich nicht («man nehme *hinein wenig* Salz»).
- Eine andere mögliche Wortart ist die Gradpartikel. Eine solche müsste jedoch betonbar sein («man nehme SEHR wenig Salz»), was aber hier nicht gegeben ist.

Comment: Bist du aus der Schweiz? Die Verwendung von «Guillemets», bei denen die Pfeile nach außen zeigen, ist nämlich eine Schweizerische Eigenheit. Im Rest des deutschen Sprachraums verwendet man »Chevrons«, das sind eigentlich dieselben Zeichen, nur werden sie so gesetzt, dass die Pfeile nach innen zeigen. Details stehen im Wikipedia-Artikel über [Guillemets](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemets).

Comment: Mich wundert: Du hast die Frage nicht editiert, keinen Kommentar abgegeben um die Frage zu bemängeln und nicht vorgeschlagen sie zu schließen. Du beantwortest sie, musst sie also verstanden haben und einer Antwort wert befunden haben. Wieso wertest Du sie dann nicht hoch?

Comment: Man schreibt «schweizerisch» klein, im Gegensatz zum Adjektiv «Schweizer». 

Answer (score 1):

Im Prinzip ist es ein Artikel. Der "Trick" ist aber, dass diese Phrasen (ein wenig, ein bisschen, ein paar, usw.) als feste Einheiten/Fügungen betrachtet werden. Im Satzbau ist also im Prinzip die ganze Phrase ein Artikelwort/Determinativ, Pronomen oder Adverb.

> Artikelwort: [ {Ein bisschen} Bewegung ] tut gut.
>
> Pronomen: Er hat [ein paar] getrunken.
>
> Adverb/Gradadverb: Das war [ {ein wenig} doof ] von mir.

Das schließt aber nicht unbedingt aus, dass "ein" (oder "kein") flektiert wird. Grammatik kann man halt in der Pfeife rauchen...

Comment: Dass die ganze Phrase ein Synonym für die Gradpartikel *etwas* ist, habe ich in der verlinkten Frage ausführlich behandelt. Hier geht es aber ganz ausdrücklich *nicht* um die ganze Phrase, sondern um ein Wort *innerhalb* dieser Phrase.

Comment: Auch an Dich die Frage: Du hast die Frage nicht editiert, keinen Kommentar abgegeben um die Frage zu bemängeln und nicht vorgeschlagen sie zu schließen. Du beantwortest sie, musst sie also verstanden und einer Antwort wert befunden haben. Wieso wertest Du sie dann nicht hoch?