# "I can understand SOME German" in German

Tags: word-choice

I want to say that:

> I speak **a little** German. But I can **understand** some German.

I mean that I can understand spoken German more than I can speak it.

The first phrase could be translated as either:

> Ich spreche *nur ein bisschen* Deutsch

or

> Ich spreche **nur ein wenig** Deutsch.

I've heard that the second phrase could be translated as:

> Aber ich kann **ein wenig** Deutsch verstehen.

But I'm not sure if that is accurate, because *"ein wenig"* is the same as *"a little"*, and what I really want to say is *"some"* and not *"a little"*. Maybe I should use *"etwas"* instead?

Comment: There is no difference in meaning between those two phrases, neither one with *etwas*. Context is key, and the word *nur*. That one expresses you are sorry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would you say, "I speak a little bit German"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38750/how-would-you-say-i-speak-a-little-bit-german)

Comment: This is clearly **not** a duplicate. He asks how to emphasise that he understands more German than he speaks himself.

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to say with the words *bisschen*, *wenig* and even *etwas* are more or less synonymous in this case. You actually provided us already with a good way to express it in English:

> I can understand spoken German more than I can speak it.

So let's just phrase that in German

> Ich verstehe Deutsch besser als ich es sprechen kann.

Alternatively, if you want to use the adjectives that you provided

> Ich spreche nur ein wenig Deutsch, aber dafür kann ich ein bisschen mehr verstehen.

By using *mehr* you emphasise that *ein bisschen* is more than just *ein wenig*.

Comment: I would skip the "dafür". It seems to imply the OP's speaking skills are somehow intentionally low so they could be better at comprehension, which is nonsensical.

Comment: I don't see this implication at all.

Comment: What does the "dafür" express in your opinion, if not "in exchange for that"/"as a compensation for that"?

Comment: Yes, it is a compensation, but I don't see how that would implicate intention. It's the same as in "Ich habe das alte Auto meiner Tante geschenkt bekommen. Es ist zwar nicht schnell, aber dafür geräumig." There's also no intention in that sentence.